# Are the sentences 这个杯子有一点儿水 and 一点儿水在杯子里 correct?

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure

I want to say there is a little bit/some water in the cup.
Can I say either of these sentences to convey that message?

> 这个杯子有一点儿水。
>
> 一点儿水在杯子里。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 这个杯子有一点儿水 (this cup has some water) sounds like 这个杯子 is the subject and it possesses some water
>
> A better phrasing should be 这个杯子里有一点儿水 (inside this cup, there's some water)

~

> 一点儿水在杯子里 (some water inside the cup) lack a verb, thus make it an incomplete sentence
>
> A better phrasing should be 有一点儿水在杯子里。(There is some water inside the cup)

- 这个杯子里有一点儿水 emphasizes the cup (*pay attention to the cup, there's some water in it*)
- 有一点儿水在杯子里 emphasizes the water (*pay attention to the water, it is in a cup*)

You can use either one